# What folder structure should I follow in Hapijs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, plugins, hapi.js

I am having all the routes, methods, strategies, plugins and db connection in a single file 'server.js'. And this is working fine. But I want modular structure where the controllers, route, db are seperately defined. I used to modulate it, but stucking that how to call my multiple strategies in some of the routes and also how to call my db connection, the connection is established but I am unable to call it in the controllers. I am using hapi-mongodb plugin fo db connection. Please could anybody tell me how do I structure my files?

Answer (score 0):

I use in my personal project the structure of `start-hapiness` project.

On this branch, have a simple example of a TODO list using Hapi + Mongoose and some cool plugins, modular and easily extensive!

https://github.com/thebergamo/start-hapiness/tree/dev-2.0

Answer (score -2):

I think for modular MEAN application, angular-fullstack is best.

Comment: I knew about MEAN. I am asking about Hapijs as I am building restful API.

Comment: Anyways I did it :)